# need to merge json in webpack 2 bundles

Tags: angularjs, json, webpack, internationalization

I need to make localization .json files for each entry point and language.

We developing angular application, where each directive can have it's own locale .json files for all languages.

So it would be great to combine them to a single file for language for each entry point:
index.en.json, index.ru.json, index.cn.json, anotherEntry.en.json, anotherEntry.ru.json, anotherEntry.cn.json

tried to use

```
const extractJSON = new ExtractTextPlugin({
filename: '[name].locale.json',
allChunks: true
});
loaders: [
    ...
    {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: extractJSON.extract({
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'raw-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'json-loader'
                }
            ]
        })
    }
],
plugins: [..., extractJSON ]
```

and bunch of different loaders...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                  loader: 'json-loader'
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.json')
    ]
```

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: json-loader with extract-text-plugin-rc3(latest for webpack 2) gives an error "Module build failed: TypeError: text.forEach is not a function"

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct plugin? `extract-text-webpack-plugin` ?

Comment: yes. I solved that a couple days ago and will write an answer as soon as got time for that - i made simple plugin with loader. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

@AwokeN Please check this webpack plugin merge-jsons-webpack-plugin.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-jsons-webpack-plugin

Comment: tried that, but it cannot generate .json for each entry point, and doesn't work with modules loaded by require() or import()

Comment: I didnt get you ,what you meant by each entry point....for example if you have 3 json files in  /node_modules/module1/...  /node_modules/Module2 you can specifiy this as an input and it we club all the three json into one json file, you can specify any number of groupings as such. By the way is your json available at compile time or run time?

Comment: hmm..I'll try to explain but that would be quite hard with my english) For example - we got an app with different frontend modules - auth and mainPage. So it would be nice to separate that logic in different modules -  maybe tomorrow we'll have another page module that would need an auth logic, and the would be 2 entry points in app(or three if we separate auth module), and each module can have it's own css, js, templates, and localization. And the last thing was exactly what i was asking about. Sorry if explanation is not good.

Comment: by the way - i found solution. thank you for trying to help me)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ExtractTextPlugin` for that. It is for css and it prforms some css preprocessing. It substitute `@import` statements and so on.

To merge json files use [merge-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/oklas/merge-webpack-plugin)

Example configuration:

```
MergePlugin = require("merge-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(json)$/i, use: [ MergePlugin.loader() ],
        // also yaml there too
        test: /\.(yaml)$/i, use: [ MergePlugin.loader(), 'yaml-loader' ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MergePlugin({
      search: './src/**/*.json',
      group: '[name]',
    })
  ]
}
```

It this example files will be devided into groups by filename. Each group will be loaded and merged and saved into destination json file. To require destination merged file you only need to require one its source file and load it.